# Slow boot after upgrading to 17.10

Tags: boot, upgrade, 17.04, 17.10

So I don't really own a fast laptop, but still I noticed the booting is slow after upgrading from *17.04* to *17.10*. 
I have a *hp pavilion Intel Core i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4 and 8gb ram*.
I tried to disable some services yet the booting is still slow.

```
user@user-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ systemd-analyze 
Startup finished in 2.673s (firmware) + 6.926s (loader) + 5.994s (kernel) +  1min 13.710s (userspace) = 1min 29.304s

user@user-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ systemd-analyze blame
         38.991s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         11.179s dev-sda3.device
          8.352s grub-common.service
          8.245s accounts-daemon.service
          7.859s gpu-manager.service
          7.717s networking.service
          7.708s NetworkManager.service
          7.707s apport.service
          6.671s snapd.service
          6.164s udisks2.service
          5.942s apparmor.service
          5.471s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          4.180s apache-htcacheclean.service
          4.162s plymouth-read-write.service
          3.459s repowerd.service
          3.210s systemd-logind.service
          3.169s avahi-daemon.service
          2.818s upower.service
          2.809s kerneloops.service
          2.361s wpa_supplicant.service
          2.308s lm-sensors.service
          2.279s fwupd.service
          2.059s rsyslog.service
          1.973s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-16A3\x2d32AD.service
          1.958s thermald.service
          1.858s polkit.service
          1.420s systemd-rfkill.service
          1.188s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
          1.111s keyboard-setup.service
          1.081s systemd-resolved.service
          1.036s gdm.service
          1.017s user@1000.service
           976ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
           966ms systemd-udevd.service
           943ms dns-clean.service
           928ms user@128.service
           909ms colord.service
           886ms pppd-dns.service
           854ms alsa-restore.service
           834ms systemd-modules-load.service
           784ms plymouth-start.service
           736ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           703ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
           678ms packagekit.service
           579ms dev-mqueue.mount
           542ms systemd-update-utmp.service
```

Comment: Did you choose the option to encrypt your home directory?

Comment: No I did not choose to  encrypt the home directory